# How to keep the terminal open if I run the python application by double clicking it?

Tags: windows-xp, terminal, python

I'm using Python in Windows XP.

I'm running a python program by double clicking on it since it is a shared folder and I cannot refer to that file from terminal.

It works well, but the terminal window is now closing when the app quits and I cannot debug properly.

I've tried to use a batch file with statement "pause" but I have some issues with the application. I was wondering if there is an option in python to specify to pause the application in the terminal before to quit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to pause terminal output is to print a prompt such as : "Hit enter to continue" and then do a readln from the terminal device.

Comment: yeah but the point is that I need to add a prompt statement in the code to each exception then, because the terminal quits when the program ends, and the program can end with an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Open up a terminal window and type `python` followed by the path to the .py script:

```
python \\serverName\shareName\subdir\myscript.py
```

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import atexit
atexit.register(lambda: raw_input("Press Enter."))
```

Comment: The *Low quality* review queue would like you to expand your answer a little ;)

Comment: The other side of the *Low quality* review queue thinks this answer is reasonable if you know Python.